# how to convert basic php script to codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm doing a snippet autocomplete code using ajax modal in php. It's success already. I can make searching by enter productName or productCode in my modal. But my problem is now i want to convert this code into codeigniter framework. I'm already try create a Controller, Model and view, but data not appear when i make a searching in my modal. My output should be same as when i using basic php.

my sample data is
productCode: s1
productName: test
price: 22.50

my success output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpztL.png)

my file is:
ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
if(!empty($_POST['type'])) {
   $type = $_POST['type'];
   $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
   $query = "SELECT productCode, productName, buyPrice FROM products where quantityInStock !=0 and UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
   $data = array();
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $name = $row['productCode'].'|'.$row['productName'].'|'.$row['buyPrice'];
    array_push($data, $name);
   }    
   echo json_encode($data);
   // exit;
  }
?>
```

view file: index.php

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
    type = $(this).data('type');

    if(type =='productCode' )autoTypeNo=0;
    if(type =='productName' )autoTypeNo=1;  

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                         name_startsWith: request.term,
                         type: type
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            var code = item.split("|");
                        return {
                            label: code[autoTypeNo],
                            value: code[autoTypeNo],
                            data : item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,            
        minLength: 0,
        appendTo: "#modal-fullscreen",
        select: function( event, ui ) {
              var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
              id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
              id = id_arr.split("_");
              console.log(names, id);

            $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
            $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
            $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);
            $('#price_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
            $('#total_'+id[1]).val( 1*names[2] );
            calculateTotal();
        }               
    });
});
```

From basic, im try convert it to codeigniter. my code is below

Controller: Invoice.php

```
  function search()
  {
    $type = $this->input->post('type');
    $name = $this->input->post('name_startsWith');

    $data = array();
    $result = $this->invoice_model->getInvoice($type,$name);

    foreach ($result as $row):
        $name = $row->productCode.'|'.$row->productName.'|'.$row->buyPrice;
        array_push($data, $name);
    endforeach;

    $data['res_invoice'] = json_encode($data);
    $data['view_content'] = "invoice/search";
    $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
}
```

Model: Invoice_model.php

```
public function getInvoice($type,$name)
{
    $this->db->select('productCode, productName, buyPrice');
    $this->db->like('productCode', $name, 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    return $query->result();
}
```

and for my view, now i change for ajax code
      url : 'ajax.php',
      to url : base_url('dentist/search')

then when i run in this codeigniter code, no result appear, seem like its cannot find my query search.

but if i echo json data, its show my data ["s1|test|22.5","s2|testing|43.5"] from db.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm found the solution
add exit(); after foreach

```
  endforeach;
  exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller allow control access

```
public function __construct($config = 'rest')
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: still cannot akses

Comment: success:function(data){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                           document.getElementById('elementName').value = obj.variableName;
                }

Comment: any other suggestion? could u convert my ajax.php into Controller and model?